# Best practise for a lengthy form to keep use engaged

Tags: forms, best-practice

I am working on a detailed form where you have to complete the information of you as a driver (kind of a hitchhiking app).

In the field of "brand car", I'm trying to decide between these 2 options.

1. A free field where the users can write whatever they want.
2. A database where they choose their corresponding brand.

I want to keep the form filling process swift and easy. **What would be the best approach to achieve that?**

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good practice to allow the users to make fewer errors. In case of a free text field, users are bound to make typos. This will also reduce the quality of the data you collect. Best interaction would be a searchable drop down. The user starts typing, and then selects from the filtered list. Hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: +1 Searchable dropdown. I would add with the possibility to submit a brand not present in the results.

Answer (score 2):

This is a crossroads moment and you have to be very clever about what you want to achieve.

As far as the **Car Brand** field is concerned, provide a [combo-box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742404(v=vs.85).aspx) for fields where exact information is necessary or the dropdown is too big. The Car Brand field fits perfectly in this category.

Now, let's talk about making a lengthy or detailed form feel easy to fill.

The key here is to break it down into logical categories and make each header a **step** like:

- Personal info (given that you're working on a hitchhiking app, you want people to be verified and be anonymous at the same time). Ask for the name and age or maybe use FB, Twitter, G Plus to verify them but promise to (and actually do) keep the details secret. Just take the bare minimum.
- Car info - Like brand  and name or keep it simple and just ask them the **number of seats** because that is the only important requirement here
- Details that are pertinent like personal car ethics, rules, etc.

Another way to keep the user engaged for a longer time is to have *avatars or characters on the page*. Not conventional, but it works. Take Google Now's weather card as an example. *The frog does make the info more interesting*

Hope this helps